# Height calculation with CSS calc() math method

Tags: css, css-calc

I have a CSS layout issue in my application, you can reproduce it here with [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/naktn0nq/).

Basically, it is quite simple as following:

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
   background: yellow;
   height: 50px;
}
.main {
   background: green;
   height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Create a div that stretches across the window, with a 50px gap between both sides of the div and the edges of the window:</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

The header div is set to fixed height with `50px`, and I want the main div to occupy the remaining height, so I use `calc(100% - 50px)`.

But the result is a little strange for me. The produced height is not accurate, and a vertical scrollbar was generated. And I have checked the margin or padding, no problem.

My desired result is the whole page divided into two parts. And no scroll bar produced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some `margin` (about `8px`) set by the browser by default, reset that to `0`.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
}
.main {
  background: green;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Create a div that stretches across the window, with a 50px gap between both sides of the div and the edges of the window:</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Pangloss says above, the browser automatically adds margin to the page causing that issue. A great way to prevent that and other different browser quirks is to use [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) in your CSS build process or link to the CDN in the `<head>`.